# How to reset $1 perl variable?

Tags: regex, perl

I try to do regex matching:

```
$address =~ s/$re_region//;
$new_address_h->{ region     } =  $1  //'';

# $1 =  undef; # ERROR: Modification of a read-only value attempted at ...
$address =~ s/$re_city//;
$new_address_h->{ city       } =  $1;
```

When city is not matched I want it is filled with `undef`. But when `city` is not matched `$1` has value from previous match. Why? I expect that when matching fails then its output has no values, even special variables. like `eval` flushes `$@`

Is it possible without additional `if`s?

Comment: If the city match fails, do you want to set `$new_address_h->{city} =undef`, or do you want to skip the assignment altogether?

Comment: @chepner: I explicitly write that I want to store matched value. Nothing is mathched, so nothig (`undef`) should be stored, should not? I did not write: store values from previous matching

Comment: There is a difference between the key `city` mapping to the value `undef` and the key `city` not existing in the hash at all. That's what I'm asking.

Comment: @chepner: Yes, I want to save `undef` there. I write about that explicitly.

Comment: Why? So you can do `s/(foo)// || s/(bar)//`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's documented behaviour ([perlvar](http://p3rl.org/perlvar)):

> Perl sets these variables when it has a successful match, so you should check the match result before using them.

You can use [do](http://p3rl.org/do) with a ternary operator to populate the hash:

```
$new_address_h->{region} = do { $address =~ s/$re_region// ? $1 : undef };
$new_address_h->{city}   = do { $address =~ s/$re_city//   ? $1 : undef };
```

Alternatively, populate the the hash with undefs and then replace them with values if there's a match:

```
my $new_address_h = { region => undef, city => undef };
$address =~ s/$re_region// and $new_address_h->{region} = $1;
$address =~ s/$re_city//   and $new_address_h->{city}   = $1;
```

The common way is to just match, not replace, and populate in list assignment:

```
($new_address_h->{region}) = $address =~ /$re_region/;
($new_address_h->{city})   = $address =~ /$re_city/;
```

Comment: In your example code, `$1` is not set after execution, but the reason is because of the `do` blocks. The variables are dynamically scoped, which is the important distinction. If you had instead done a standard `if ($x =~ s/$r//) {...}` then `$1` is assigned the last successful match even outside of the `if` block, which can be a frustrating gotcha.

Comment: Documentation is good, but perl is not low level programming language to force programmer think about such things. I hope this can be automated in the future without much processing time penalty

Comment: @Possum: You can't use just `if ($x =~ s/$r//) { $hash{key} = $1 }` as it won't populate the hash if the regex does't match.

Comment: @EugenKonkov: I doubt this behaviour will change. See also the updated answer for some alternatives.

Comment: @EugenKonkov there really isn't any reason to change anything.  you should not be using the match variables such as `$1` unless your match was successful.

Comment: @choroba Correct, you would need an `else` clause if you wanted to populate with `undef` as was requested. I was trying to point out that `$1` is still set all the way to the end of the block where the match was performed. In your first example, you wrap it in a `do {}`, but with `if (MATCH_HERE) {} else {}` then `$1` is still assigned even afterward, because the context of the match is not constrained to inside the `if {}`. The question asks how to "reset" the variable, but that simply can't be done. For example, with the new code you added, `$1` is still around after those assignments.

Comment: @ysth: May you tell me please. Is there a reason to keep old matched values when current regex is different already? This is like if variables come with uninitialized values, to my mind.

Comment: @EugenKonkov now you can do /regex1/ || /regex2/ || /regex3/ and then use captures from whichever succeeded.  clearing the variables on failure too would break such code

Answer (score 1):

Finally I use ternary operator without `do`:

```
$new_address_h->{ region } =  $address =~ s/$re_region//?
    $1 : '';

$new_address_h->{ city   } =  $address =~ s/$re_city//?
    $1 : undef;
```